# java Hibernate setClienId и setClient

Tags: java, hibernate

Столкнулся с проблемой при создании классов из базы данных. При генерации если отметить поле client_id и связь по этому полю типа один ко многим, то генерируется код такого вида:

```
    @Basic
@Column(name = "client_id", nullable = false)
public int getClientId() {
    return clientId;
}

public void setClientId(int clientId) {
    this.clientId = clientId;
}
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "client_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
public ClientEntity getClientByClientId() {
    return clientByClientId;
}

public void setClientByClientId(ClientEntity clientByClientId) {
    this.clientByClientId = clientByClientId;
}
```

Из-за чего возникает ошибка `failedorg.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.tr1nksgroup.model.data.entities.ReturnEntity column: client_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")`
Что собственно логично и правильно.
Но мне необходимо иметь сеттер id числом и сеттер сущностью,
Возможно ли такое ?

Comment: ORM так не работает, в ORM вы работаете не с айдишниками, а с сущностями.

Comment: Согласен, но на определенном этапе мне необходимо просто задать id числом чтоб не тянуть громоздкую сущьность. Возможности совсем нет никакой ?

Comment: Потому что одно и тоже поле отображено дважды и оба раза на запись. clientId надо сделать только на чтение `@Column(name = "client_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)`

Comment: @Sergey Спасибо, так работает. А эти параметры не изменят штатное добавление сущьностью? Ведь `insertable=false` говорит что столбец не включен в `INSERT` который генерируется поставщиком

Comment: Устанавливать можно будет только через второй маппинг `clientByClientId`. Кстати чтобы не тянуть большую сущность можно попробовать получить экземпляр `ClientEntity` с помощью `EntityManager.getReference`. Такой экземпляр будет загружаться ленивым способом.

Comment: @Sergey Спасибо!!!!